# Why can't the assembly loader find the DLL which I have installed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild, azure-functions

I am working on an Azure Functions project which targets .NET Standard 2.0.

It builds successfully, but when I run it locally, the following error occurs:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I understand that it cannot find the above DLL.

What is confusing to me is that Nuget Package manager indicates that it IS installed.

I am using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to verify where the build engine is probing for this dll.

Here is where it probes for Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll

```
C:\dir1\Solution\ProjectName\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll

C:\dir1\Solution\ProjectName\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\bin\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
```

The above is confusing me because, it IS installed here:

```
C:\dir1\Solution\ProjectName\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0
```

I can see it using the File Explorer.  The precise version is 5.0.20.51904 (right-click the dll, Details tab, File version field).

However, it does **NOT** appear in

```
C:\dir1\Solution\ProjectName\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\bin\
```

No matter how many times I clean and rebuild, or manually delete the above bin folders, Microsoft.Extensions.Options is never generated in

```
C:\dir1\Solution\ProjectName\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\bin
```

At this point, I'm confused and not sure what to do next, because the binding engine is telling me that it cannot find something, which is indeed where it is looking.  How can I solve this problem? How can I get the binding engine to use the dll which I have explicitly installed?

It also probes these folders as well:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.1\Facades\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll

C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
```

Extra info:

- Azure Functions Core Tools

  Core Tools Version:       3.0.3284 Commit hash:
  98bc25e668274edd175a1647fe5a9bc4ffb6887d

  Function Runtime Version: 3.0.15371.0

Comment: I remember this happened to me after playing with those nugget... never found a solution to this, I had to go back using previous GIT commit and NOT do it. I don't know why but what i concluded is : If I start coding using nugget I have, then update this nugget, everything is suddenly broken. Did you change nugget AFTER codding with them ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried copying the file over to that folder? Does it work then? If that works, then its a matter of using MS Build actions to ensure the dll is available in the right folder. Let me know, I'll post the entire solution on how to do this with MS Build.... ALSO, can you try downgrading the version of that nuget, its possible there is a compatibility issue - thought it doesnt seem like it from the error, but just spit balling here.